# I want to write a specific set

Tags: math-mode

```
E= {a,b)|a:b ∈ A ∧(a→b)}
```

i want to write this set in my table. please help me

Comment: Which issues are you facing? Something like `$E = \{ (a,b) \;|\; a:\, b \in A \land (a \rightarrow b) \}$` should work. Otherwise please add a MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two suggested solutions. The first is "pure (La)TeX". It uses the macros `\in`, `\land` ("logical and"), and `\to` (`\rightarrow` works too) instead of `∈`, `∧`, and `→`, respectively. Moreover, it uses `\mid` instead of `|`, as the symbol is used here as a relational operator. In fine math typography, it is customary to surround relational operators with "thickspace"  The `\mid` macro takes care of this typographic chore. Finally, I replaced `{` and `}` with `\{` and `\}`, respectively, in order to generate curly braces.

The second solution requires XeTeX and/or LuaLaTeX. Its advantage is that it lets you use the characters `∈`, `∧`, and `→` directly. Observe that I replaced `|` with `\char"2223` -- Unicode character 'DIVIDES' -- in order to get the same spacing as is afforded by `\mid`. (Still another approach would be to write `\;|\;`, where the `\;` directives insert whitespace in the amount of "thickspace".) Of course, writing `\mid`, as I did in the first solution, is at least as easy as writing `\char"2223` is.

In both solutions, the `$` symbols serve to initiate and terminate inline-math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX
\begin{document}
$E= \{ (a,b) \mid a:b \in A \land (a \to b) \}$

$E= \{ (a,b) \char"2223 a:b ∈ A ∧(a→b) \}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Then use `∣` (U+2223), not the horrible `\;|\;` (or just `\mid`, why not?)

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for this suggestion. I've modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: @egreg yay I am doing it correctly! Do you know a case where `\;|\;` is necessary instead of `\mid`? Thank you.

Comment: @manooooh None that I know, except when you have `\middle|` for the automatically enlarged symbol, when you do want to write `\;\middle|\;` to get the spacing right. When the enlargement is manual, use `\bigm|`, `\Bigm|` and so on.